# FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ubuntu, digital-ocean

My CI/CD Pipeline is getting failed every time while trying to create a production build (`npm run build`) of my React Project in Ubuntu Machine(2 GB Ram,25 GB Storage).

But when I am trying to build it on my Windows Machine( 8 GB Ram, 1 TB Storage),
then it is building successfully, But it is failing on the Ubuntu Machine - Digital Ocean.

I tried to increase the default memory allocated by Node  by running the following command -  `export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=2048`
but still, I am having the issue.

Is there any other way to increase the default memory allocated by the Node for React Project?

```
$ CI=false npm run build
> client@0.1.0 build /home/gitlab-runner-2/builds/WHJ93iRm/0/team-weanalyz/service-desk
> react-scripts build
Creating an optimized production build...
[12129:0x3441490]   163356 ms: Mark-sweep 994.2 (1005.1) -> 992.1 (1005.4) MB, 4996.1 / 0.1 ms  (average mu = 0.068, current mu = 0.013) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[12129:0x3441490]   168187 ms: Mark-sweep 994.7 (1005.4) -> 993.0 (1006.6) MB, 4794.5 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.038, current mu = 0.008) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
==== JS stack trace =========================================
    0: ExitFrame [pc: 0x13cf099]
    1: StubFrame [pc: 0x13d0133]
Security context: 0x21679f2408d1 
    2: SourceMapGenerator_serializeMappings [0x2ad643a32db1] [/home/gitlab-runner-2/builds/WHJ93iRm/0/team-weanalyz/service-desk/node_modules/source-map/lib/source-map-generator.js:~303] [pc=0x2cf51f68298d](this=0x2e99646fad91 )
    3: SourceMapGenerator_toJSON [0x2ad643a32e31] [/home/gitla...
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0xa093f0 node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0xa097fc node::OnFatalError(char const*, char const*) [node]
 3: 0xb8431e v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 4: 0xb84699 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 5: 0xd31055  [node]
 6: 0xd316e6 v8::internal::Heap::RecomputeLimits(v8::internal::GarbageCollector) [node]
 7: 0xd3df65 v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
 8: 0xd3ee15 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
 9: 0xd418cc v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFail(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node]
10: 0xd0837b v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin) [node]
11: 0x1049fbe v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInYoungGeneration(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
12: 0x13cf099  [node]
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! client@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the client@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/gitlab-runner-2/.npm/_logs/2020-10-20T10_24_20_084Z-debug.log
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

Comment: `--max_old_space_size=4096` is not going to do anything on a machine with only 2GB of memory...

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have tried building it on your personal machine, the obvious problem would be that you are running out of memory:

`FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`

You can try upgrading your machine just for the sake of building it. And you can always downgrade it if that does not work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, It is getting build on My Windows Machine (8GB Ran,1 TB HDD), But it is getting failed on my Ubuntu Machine (1 GB, 25 GB). Is there anything memory allocation by Node, which can be increased?